# postgres table as source for pdal reader

Tags: postgresql, point-cloud-library

Using the point data abstraction library (PDAL), is it possible to use an existing postgis table as input to a pipeline?

I've got some older lidar data stored as xyz points in postgis - I'd like to move them into pointcloud patches without exporting them and re-importing them to improve query efficiency.

Alternatively, can the same be done within Postgis/pointcloud? Is there a way to 'chip' the input points into patches within the database?